# The roots of the characteristic polynomial and the eigenvalues are not the same

Tags: matlab, matrix, symbolic-math, polynomials, eigenvalue

This is matrix `B`

```
B = [1 2 0 ; 2 4 6 ; 0 6 5]
```

The result of `eig(B)` is:

```
{-2.2240, 1.5109, 10.7131}
```

and the characteristic polynomial of `B` by [this link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/charpoly.html) is

```
syms x
polyB = charpoly(B,x)
x^3 - 10*x^2 - 11*x + 36
```

but the answer of `solve(polyB)` is

```
133/(9*(3^(1/2)*5492^(1/2)*(i/3) + 1009/27)^(1/3)) + ((3^(1/2)*5492^(1/2)*i)/3 + 1009/27)^(1/3) + 10/3
 (3^(1/2)*(133/(9*(3^(1/2)*5492^(1/2)*(i/3) + 1009/27)^(1/3)) - ((3^(1/2)*5492^(1/2)*i)/3 + 1009/27)^(1/3))*i)/2 - 133/(18*(3^(1/2)*5492^(1/2)*(i/3) + 1009/27)^(1/3)) - ((3^(1/2)*5492^(1/2)*i)/3 + 1009/27)^(1/3)/2 + 10/3
 10/3 - 133/(18*(3^(1/2)*5492^(1/2)*(i/3) + 1009/27)^(1/3)) - ((3^(1/2)*5492^(1/2)*i)/3 + 1009/27)^(1/3)/2 - (3^(1/2)*(133/(9*(3^(1/2)*5492^(1/2)*(i/3) + 1009/27)^(1/3)) - ((3^(1/2)*5492^(1/2)*i)/3 + 1009/27)^(1/3))*i)/2
```

which I don't know what it is while I expect it to be the eigenvalues of `B`. What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not understand why you add `x` and symbolic maths, they are not required for your task.

```
B = [1 2 0 ; 2 4 6 ; 0 6 5]
cp=charpoly(B)
eig2=roots(cp)
```

returns:

```
eig2 =

   10.7131
   -2.2240
    1.5109
```

However, if for some reason you insist in using symbolic (which you should not for a numerical task), you can do

```
double(solve(polyB))

ans =

  10.7131 + 0.0000i
  -2.2240 - 0.0000i
   1.5109 - 0.0000i
```

(note imaginary parts is zero)

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo no worries ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not have MATLAB in this machine, I will use [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org) instead:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> B = Matrix([[1, 2, 0],
                [2, 4, 6],
                [0, 6, 5]])
```

Computing the **characteristic polynomial** and its roots:

```
>>> s = Symbol('s')
>>> p = (s*eye(3) - B).det()
>>> p
s**3 - 10*s**2 - 11*s + 36
>>> roots = solve(p,s)
```

Computing **floating-point** approximations of the three roots:

```
>>> [ r.evalf() for r in roots ]
[1.51092975992931 - 0.e-22*I, -2.22404024437578 + 0.e-22*I, 10.7131104844465 - 0.e-20*I]
```

Since `B` is symmetric, its eigenvalues must be real. Note that the imaginary parts of the floating-point approximations of the roots are indeed equal to zero.

Printing in LaTeX, the **exact** values of the roots are:

[image: LaTeX'ed roots]

Note that some roots are "longer" than others, i.e., they require more symbols. However, they are **exact**. Using floating-point arithmetic, all roots have the same "size", but they are approximations.