# eigenvalues of the matrix - polynomial

Tags: r

I calculate the eigenvalues of the matrix. I want to write a program that will help me (step by step). I know the eigen function, but I'd like to see a polynomial (like here) [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49939487/the-roots-of-the-characteristic-polynomial-and-the-eigenvalues-are-not-the-same)
and then calculate the polynomial elements.

I can enter a matrix, but I do not know how to enter a new matrix after subtracting "a" from the main diagonal, let alone determine the function that the polynomial (matrix determinant) will give me.

I am asking for directions
Can you do the same as "charpoly (B, x)" and solve (polyB) in R

Comment: In the future please type your input into the question so those responding can copy and paste it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `charpoly` and `roots` from the pracma package:

```
library(pracma)

m <- matrix(c(1,2,0,2,4,6,0,6,5), 3, byrow = TRUE)
cp <- charpoly(m)

cp
## [1]   1 -10 -11  36

roots(cp)
## [1] 10.71311 -2.22404  1.51093

# same (except for order)
eigen(m)$values
## [1] 10.71311  1.51093 -2.22404
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Do you know any other solutions?